# Fast navigation between selected / checked out files in Visual Studio 2008 Solutions Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, tfs

I am working on a very large product, that has hundreads of files in 5 differnt project including one web site project

All these projects loads under one Solutions in VS 2008

We are using TFS as Source Control.

I am fixing bug in this solutions , now I have to checkout various files and open other many files to search similar/related code.

I want to quickly navigate from one file to another. I really spending some time in searching for proper file that I don't want to do.

Is it possible to group checked out files in solutions explorer? or any other way to navigate between selected files.

Any other suggestion also welcome.

Comment: I don't think it's easy to group checked out files in *solution explorer*.  But can you use the pending changes view as a jump list?  This will, of course, show your checked out files, and you can double-click to open them in the editor.

Comment: do you want me to checkin on solutions and choose the file , I tried that but it not open in IDE from there , if you right click on a file and click view it opens in notepad

Comment: No, I mean the pending changes view:  Go to the View menu -> Other Windows -> Pending Changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the few tips

1. Checking out files will be done automatically when you edit a file if you have these settings in VS Tools => Options.

[image]

2. Install [VSCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf?SRC=Home) and [Productivity PowerTools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home)

[image]

**VSCommands** has some features which helps your productivity

- [Collapse All](http://vscommands.com/features/#CollapseAll)
- [Open File Location](http://vscommands.com/features/#OpenFileLocation) useful in VS2008
- [Locate Source File](http://vscommands.com/features/#LocateSourceFile)
  and lot more

[**Productivity PowerTools**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home) has some features which helps your productivity

- Quick Find (Highlights your search as you type)
- Enhanced Scroll bar (easy to navigate to edited part of the files)
- Solution Navigator (Type the file name to search)
- Ctrl + click to navigate to definition and lot more.

I use **[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)** which has most of them in it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I also used ReSharper trial version and it is good, but I don't think they have any option to quickly locate file in solutions explorer or find by name (any part)

Comment: Resharper has got Shift+Alt+L to locate files in solution explorer and Ctrl+Shift+T to Goto File. Check this http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper50DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can see what you have checked-out at a glance in the Pending Changes Window.

Go to the View menu, select Other Windows, then select Pending Changes.  This will open the Pending Changes window at the bottom of Visual Studio:

[image]

From there, you can double-click on any file to open it in the editor, or you can use the context menu to perform other operations, like comparing against the workspace version, the latest version, etc.

Comment: It's in Visual Studio Team Explorer 2005, 2008 and 2010.

Answer (score -1):

Although I didn't find any smart solution for this except using Telerik's JustCode tool.

```
http://www.telerik.com/help/justcode/code-navigation-and-search.html
```

This Tool allows me shortcut to navigate by Searching file by name and Locating file in solution explorer :)

Atleast this is giving 80% what I expected.